# Help with Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (when it is an equality) (from Apostol's Calculus)

Tags: calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

[image]
Apostol tells the reader to verify the last sentence.
I've verified the backward implication ($a_kx+b_k=0\implies \text{equality}$).
I'm having trouble verifying the forward implication. Could someone show me a proof of the forward implication?

Comment: Actually is the forward implication even true? Consider 0 as the a-sequence and 9 as the b-sequence. Clearly, the left hand side is 0, as is the right hand side. But there is no real number $x$ which will make $0x+9=9=0$ true.

Comment: Go through the proof in the book (or any other source) line by line, looking for where the inequality sign is.

If the vectors $a_k$ and $b_k$ *are not* related by a scalar multiple, you will see that the inequality must be strict. 
This will prove what you want.

Comment: You're right, the author was not careful about dealing with the case when $x$ wants to be infinity. They should've allowed the possibility $a_k+xb_k=0$ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward implication is actually false.

Counterexample:

Let $n=1$, with $a_1=0$ and $b_1=9$. Then clearly, both the left and right-hand sides of the inequality equal zero. But there is no real $x$ which will make $0x+9=9=0$ true.

Answer (score 0):

If we have equality then $\mid x\cdot y\mid^2=\mid x\mid^2\cdot \mid y\mid^2$.  But lhs$=\mid x\mid^2\cdot \mid y\mid^2\cos^2\theta$.  $\therefore \cos^2\theta=1\implies \theta =0$ or $\pi\implies $ the angle between $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ is $0$ or $\pi$.  So they are multiples of each other; or one of them is zero.